# GridView headers not displaying if datasource is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am totally confused.

If Datasource has no rows, my DataGridView headers who has columns that are databound, does not display.  Only the one column that is not databound, fills the entire grid.

How can I resolve this?

I am using Windows Forms development, in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Did you have `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `True` on `DataGridView`?

Comment: Try editing and adding columns using    DataGridView Tasks tab.

Comment: @sthotakura I forgot about that property.  Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the AutoGenerateColumns to false.

Thanks to @shotakura.